# What is the name of this stitching pattern?

Tags: sewing

I've been looking around on google but can't seem to find anything similar to this:

[image]

I'd like to know what is the name of that stitching pattern. This is a Chanel dress made out of cotton (search: "Chanel White Pure Cotton Sleeveless Shift Dress with Flowers"). It is also sold on [this website](https://www.reebonz.com/ch/chanel/clothing/chanel-white-pure-cotton-sleeveless-shift-dress-with-flowers-size-40-12186626).

I've looked for "tuck" stitching, but it's not quite that.

Can anyone help me on this one? I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [filet crochet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filet_crochet) (aka "filet lace") because of the very regular, very angular squares. The thread seems to be very thin and slightly fluffy / fleecy because you cannot see the individual stitches.

[image]
[Image source and instruction](https://www.yarnspirations.com/row-en/filet-crochet-patterns-and-guides.html)

[image]
[Image source, instructions and tips](https://www.interweave.com/article/crochet/7-tips-filet-crochet/)

And Chanel wasn't the first to get the idea of creating a piece of clothing with filet lace, as proven by this page of a 2008 crochet handbook (German):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! What the lady is wearing looks very much like the dress. Your help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Possible knit stitches. 
From book: *Knitting Dictionary 800 stitches & patterns* by Margaret Hamilton-Hunt Crown Publishing 1963.

[image: mock Tunisian I]
[image: more mock Tunisian]

Lace: “cellular”
[image: cellular knit stitches]

You might have luck looking up “open work.” There are a few styles of open work.
[image: openwork]

Also esparto stitch or honeycombe.
[image: esparto]
[image: honeycombe]

Hope these help in your search!